# How to in a viewClass notify another View class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

My first view PageView.m like this

> `PageView.m`

```
albumListView = [[AlbumListView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 45, 480)];
albumListView.tag = 1001;
[self addSubview:albumListView];
albumListView.hidden = YES;
[albumView release];
```

I want when my CameraView moved set albumListView.hidden = NO.
How to do it!

> `CameraView.m`

```
-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
}
```

How to use delegate or other ways?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `PageView` class is where the `CameraView` instance is created, you can do sthg like this:

In your `CameraView` class, define a protocol like this:

```
@class CameraView;
@protocol CameraViewDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (void)cameraViewMoved:(CameraView *)view;
@end
```

Then, in the same class implement a property to hold your delegate:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<CameraViewDelegate> delegate;
```

In your CameraView implementation file, call your delegate's cameraViewMoved method when you want to notify it, like this:

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(cameraViewMoved:)]) {
        [self.delegate cameraViewMoved:self];
}
```

Make your `PageView` class a delegate of your `CameraView`, by putting sthg like this in your PageView.h file:

```
@interface PageView : <CameraViewDelegate>
```

And in PageView.m class, first set yourself as the delegate of your cameraView by doing sthg like `cameraView.delegate = self;`
Then, implement the protocol method `cameraViewMoved`. Inside this method, you can do what you need.

Comment: And don't forget to add "@class CameraView" so your compiler knows you are going to implement CameraView later (because you reference it above the CameraView interface, so, compiler doesn't know what CameraView is yet).